# Using AngularJS interpolation binding, `{{ }}`, with dot notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use the AngularJS [interpolation binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) with dot notation.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="form.city.{{item.region}}.enabled">
</div>
```

The `ng-model` gives me errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ng-model="form.city[item.region].enabled"` should work

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: @emed you should add that as an answer

Comment: @MarcusH I though this question would be closed as a typo, thats why I put in a comment

Comment: make it so with your votes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ng-model value is considered an angular [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so there is no need to use braces.

`ng-model="form.city[item.region].enabled"` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> #### Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice:
>
> - It increases the complexity of the markup
> - There is no guarantee that it works for every directive, because interpolation itself is a directive. If another directive accesses attribute data before interpolation has run, it will get the raw interpolation markup and not data.
> - It impacts performance, as interpolation adds another watcher to the scope.
> - Since this is not recommended usage, we do not test for this, and changes to AngularJS core may break your code.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - mixing interpolation and expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)